# Result starts with someone who is not a friend in Facebook search

Tags: facebook, search

I've noticed that recently when I enter a letter into the search bar, the first person that comes up isn't a friend of mine, but the rest are. Does anyone know why this person comes up first?

Answer (score 1):

Normally it will list your friends. If not it will list the recommended friends like friends of friends

Answer (score 1):

The search is performed across *all* Facebook, not just across your group of friends and the results returned take into account several parameters, not just your friends: it might be that you searched for that person in the past, or that you visited his/her profile, or that is friend of friends. Or is somewhat famous, thus having a higher “search rank.”